# Error 1119 in Actionscript 3 (as3) Access of possibly undefined property text through a reference with static type money_txt

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is in the main class

```
package  {


import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
public class main extends MovieClip {
    public var scene = 0;
    public var _money = 0;
    public var gain = 1;
    public var clicks = 0;

    public function main() {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        mainbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handler);
        playbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playHandler);

    }
        var mainbtn:button = new button();
        var playbtn:playbutton = new playbutton();
        var playtxt:playtext = new playtext();
        var cash:money_txt = new money_txt();
        var scene0:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        var scene1:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

    public function loop(e:Event):void {
        if(scene == 0) {
            addChild(scene0)
            scene0.addChild(playbtn);
            playbtn.x = 300;
            playbtn.y = 200;

            scene0.addChild(playtxt);
            playtxt.x = 300;
            playtxt.y = 100;
        } else {
            scene0.removeChild(playbtn);
            scene0.removeChild(playtxt);
        }
        if(scene == 1) {
            addChild(scene1);
            scene1.addChild(mainbtn);
            mainbtn.x = 300;
            mainbtn.y = 200;
            scene1.addChild(cash);
            cash.text = 'Money: ' + _money.toString();
        } else {
            scene1.removeChild(mainbtn);
        }
    }


    public function playclickHandler(e:MovieClip) {
        scene = 1;
    }
    public function handler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        _money += gain;
        clicks++;
        trace('yep');
    }
    public function playHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
        scene = 1;
    }
}
```

}
And This is where the error would be
C:\Users\Slime\Desktop\Art-ish\game\main.as, Line 47, Column 10 1119: Access of possibly undefined property text through a reference with static type money_txt.

Thanks for helping if you can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these should be defined as public

```
public var mainbtn:button = new button();
public var playbtn:playbutton = new playbutton();
public var playtxt:playtext = new playtext();
public var cash:money_txt = new money_txt();
public var scene0:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
public var scene1:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
```

also it is hard to tell if money_txt, playtext, playbutton and button are classes or MovieClip instances. Convention dictates that Classes should start with a capital letter and instances with lower.

**update**

The issue is that if button and playbutton are buttons and playtext and money_txt are MovieClips, you should instantiate them as such.

for example if you have

```
public var mainbtn:button = new button();
```

but there is no class with name of `button`, `mainbtn` will be null. What you may need to do is

```
public var mainbtn:Button;
public var cash:MovieClip;
```

and as a part of your main or some other function, assign the instances

```
mainbtn = this['button'];
cash = this['money_txt'];
```

you can check if this worked by checking `trace(cash);`, which will return null if the assignment did not work.

I should stress again though, it is hard to to know what exactly is going wrong without knowing what your setup is. I'm assuming `money_txt` and the other classes you are defining are not actually classes with their own linkage IDs, but buttons and movieclips inside the MovieClip or stage you are putting this code in.